# Event-driven architecture and synchronization with a "First-timer microservice"

Tags: microservices, event-programming, eventual-consistency

I'm working on a distributed application and getting deeper into Event-Driven architectures with Microservices. Let's say I have been running two Microservices, `CustomerService` and `AccountService`. They both have their own database, and they've been keeping in sync with an event-style messaging with RabbitMQ in between.

For example, when a new user is created in the `CustomerService`, a `CustomerCreated` event is sent to RabbitMQ. The `AccountService` has a subscriber that listens to this event and immediately creates an account for this user.

Now, several years in the future, I want have a new service, `MusicListService`, that whenever a new `CustomerCreated` event is raised, bind a Music playlist to that user. Obviously the previously created users need to have a playlist binded to them as well. But since this service is brand-new, it didn't receive the past `CustomerCreated` from the former years, so no playlist will be binded for the former users unless I create some kind of out-of-band script that brings the database to a proper, up-to-today state.

What would be the best start-up strategy to a new Microservice so that it keeps in sync with the ones that were already existing?

Comment: It may not solve this issue but you should look at [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/).  It's structured in a way that eliminates a lot of messaging challenges.  For example, if you were keeping all events (years might be tough) there would be no extra work to handle this.  All the events would be available to the new subscriber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you take a snapshot in time of existing data and either process that snapshot via an external process or by replaying the snapshot’s messages over the bus/queue.

Practically, you’ll need to account for out of order messages, as well as duplicate messages because the snapshot and normal message stream need to overlap a little to ensure there’s no gaps (and thus missing data). But you should already be accommodating for that since you’re using a messaging system.

Comment: Agree with @Telastyn, basically you have to ensure that your events are idempotent and possibly independent (though that is dependent on how you have actually broken your services). 

So even if there's some overlap, or out of order scenario, it would not result in an inconsistent state of your data.

Comment: Resending it over the queue for the sake of one consumer catching up is a bad idea as you're creating an invalid truth. A CustomerCreated event may only be issued once to preserve integrity. You can however resend a CustomerUpdated event and make sure that in your new Consumer you do an upsert when you spot a CustomerUpdated event